# Having both bearer token and basic authentications

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

In my asp.net web API, I have a couple of controllers. In one of my controllers, I am using basic authentication and in another one, I am using bearer token authentication. It is working as it is expected, I wonder if are there any improvements to make it better. So I would be glad if you can share your comments.

Controller A -> Basic Authentication -> 401 if Basic Authentication fails

Controller B -> Bearer Token Authentication -> 401 if Bearer Token Authentication fails

#### Owin Startup

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
        Configure(app, config.DependencyResolver);

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
        config.EnsureInitialized();
    }

    private static void Configure(IAppBuilder app, IDependencyResolver resolver)
    {
        var options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
            Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider((IUserValidate)resolver.GetService(typeof(IUserValidate)))
        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    }
}
```

#### WebApiConfig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling =
            DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "DefaultApi",
            "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
        );
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new RequestResponseHandler());
        config.Filters.Add(new CustomExceptionFilter());
    }
}
```

#### Authorization Server Provider

```
public class AuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private readonly IUserValidate _userValidate;
    public AuthorizationServerProvider(IUserValidate userValidate)
    {
        _userValidate = userValidate;
    }
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        if (!context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out var clientId, out var clientSecret))
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            context.Rejected();
            return;
        }    
        if (_userValidate.Login(clientId, clientSecret))
        {
            context.Validated();
        }
    }    
    
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
           
        if (_userValidate.Login(context.UserName, context.Password))
        {                    
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "admin"));

            context.Validated(identity);
        }
        else
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Basic Authentication Attribute

```
public class CustomBasicAuthenticationAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    [Dependency] public static IUserValidate authentication { get; set; }

    private const string Realm = "My Realm";
    

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var requestScope = actionContext.Request.GetDependencyScope();

        //If the Authorization header is empty or null
        //then return Unauthorized
        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization == null)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request
                .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            // If the request was unauthorized, add the WWW-Authenticate header 
            // to the response which indicates that it require basic authentication
            if (actionContext.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                actionContext.Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate",
                    $"Basic realm=\"{Realm}\"");
        }
        else
        {
            //Get the authentication token from the request header
            var authenticationToken = actionContext.Request.Headers
                .Authorization.Parameter;
            try
            {
                //Decode the string
                var decodedAuthenticationToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
                    Convert.FromBase64String(authenticationToken));
                //Convert the string into an string array
                var usernamePasswordArray = decodedAuthenticationToken.Split(':');
                //First element of the array is the username
                var username = usernamePasswordArray[0];
                //Second element of the array is the password
                var password = usernamePasswordArray[1];

                authentication = requestScope.GetService(typeof(IUserValidate)) as IUserValidate; 

                if (authentication != null && authentication.Login(username, password))
                {
                    var identity = new GenericIdentity(username);
                    IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
                    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
                    if (HttpContext.Current != null) HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
                }
                else
                {
                    actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request
                        .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request
                    .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Controller A

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v2/game")]
public class LoadTestController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IGameServicesTest _gameServices;
     
    public LoadTestController(IGameServicesTest gameServices)
    {
        _gameServices = gameServices;
    }

    [CustomBasicAuthentication]

    [HttpPost, Route("purchase")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PurchaseGame(RequestDto game)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

#### Controller B

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/v2/game/abc101")]
public class ABC101Controller : ApiController
{
    private readonly IGameServicesABC101 _gameServices;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    //private readonly IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider _providerService;

    public ABC101Controller(IGameServicesABC101 gameServices, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _gameServices = gameServices;
        _mapper = mapper;
        
    }

    [HttpPost]
    
    [Route("purchase")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PurchaseGame(RequestDto game)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: From what aspect are you looking for review? Legibility, maintenance, security or something else?

Comment: mostly maintenance and security perspectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this post I will focus only on the security aspect.

### Authentication vs Authorization

- Based on your question I'm not sure that you have a clear understanding about these concepts

  - **Authentication**: verify that the requester is that person/entity who (s)he/it claims
  - **Authorization**: verify that the authenticated identity has the required privilege to execute the requested action
- In case of WebApi we have two core interfaces:

  - `IIdentity`: represents the authenticated person/entity
  - `IPrinciple`: represents the security context via the identity and its related roles
- Nowadays we usually use the `ClaimsPrinciple` where facts about the identity and his/her roles are represented as claims

### Basic Authentication

- First of all you should not use this protocol at all

  - It is **not secure by any means** it is just an obfuscated way to pass credentials
  - [OWASP](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Web_Service_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html#user-authentication) also suggests to try to [prevent it](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/owasp/RSPEC-2647)
- The only viable place where it could make sense is **intranet** (not over the internet)

  - But here you should also consider to use it **over TLS** (encrypted channel)
- You have implemented your Basic Auth handler as `AuthorizationFilterAttribute`

  - I assume you did it because you have followed [this article](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/web-api-basic-authentication/)
  - In case of WebApi 2 you should not need to reinvent the wheel since we have there `IdentityBasicAuthenticationAttribute` [filter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters), which inherits from [`BasicAuthenticationAttribute`](https://github.com/aspnet/samples/blob/main/samples/aspnet/MVC/BasicAuthentication/BasicAuthentication/Filters/IdentityBasicAuthenticationAttribute.cs) and that implements the `IAuthenticationFilter` interface
  - In case of .NET Core we have [`AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>`](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/basic-authentication-asp-net-core-with-csharp-example/) which implements [`IAuthenticationHandler`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.iauthenticationhandler?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and shifts from the filter concept to a handler one

### Token based Authentication

- In WebAPI you can only achieve it via `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`

  - Which is bad since [OAuth 2](https://medium.com/identity-beyond-borders/oauth-2-0-basics-3d06bce33870) is an authorization protocol not an authentication one

    - [OpenId Connect](https://openid.net/connect/) is the related authentication protocol
    - In OAuth 2 there are an authorzation server and a resource server entities
    - But with this .NET class you have to implement both sides :(

      - I have seen a dozen of implementations where the authentication was part of the `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method and the `ValidateClientAuthentication` simply called the `context.Validated`